# How to smooth Fourier spectral curves with a 0.2 Hz Parzen window in Python

Tags: python, fft, smoothing

I am trying to apply a window function to smooth my signal.Yet I do not know how to apply smoothing windows for frequency domain. But I can't reproduce the effect in the article.Should I use convolution for the Fourier amplitude spectrum of the window and Fourier amplitude spectrum of the data? But this smoothed amplitude is very large.And when I tried to add a 0.2Hz window to the time domain before, he showed that the window size didn't match the data.

What is the meaning of smoothing window length with 0.1 Hz or 0.2 Hz?

Here are my results figure
[image: Here are my results figure.]

Here are artical figure
[image: Here are artical figure]

I tried the following code:

```
tt = pd.read_csv(r"D:\accelerate.csv",header=None,skiprows=2,usecols=range(5))

accelerate_data = tt.iloc[:, -3:].values
# Remove DC offset
column_means = np.mean(accelerate_data, axis=0)
accelerate_data_centered = accelerate_data - column_means
# Apply Fourier transform
# Apply the Parzen window
fft_result = abs(rfft(accelerate_data_centered[:, 0], axis=0))
# Calculate the frequency axis
N = len(accelerate_data_centered[:, 1])
frequency_axis = rfftfreq(n=N, d=1 / fs)  # 1/1000 represents the sampling frequency in Hz

# Define the Parzen window
sampling_frequency = 1000.0  # Assume a sampling frequency of 1 Hz
window_width_hz = 0.2  # Window width of 0.2 Hz
window_width_samples = int((1 / window_width_hz) * sampling_frequency)

# Use SciPy to apply the Parzen window smoothing
smoothed_flux = scipy.signal.windows.parzen(window_width_samples)  # Create the Parzen window

# Perform the smoothing operation
smoothed_data = np.convolve(fft_result, smoothed_flux, mode='same')

# Plot the frequency domain graph
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
# plt.plot(frequency_axis, fft_result)
plt.plot(frequency_axis, smoothed_data, color="r")

plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('0.2 Hz Parzen Window Smooth')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```